# && and || in while loop problems

Tags: java, operators

I have been assigned to make a dice game of high or low for my intro to java course. I have all the methods completed, however, I need to use a while loop so that I can continue to play the game until my cash hits 0 or if I bet 0 dollars. I do not want to use a break if I do not have to. So my question is what can I do (if possible) to just only use the while loop? Here is my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cash = 100;
    int bet = 1

    while(cash > 0 || bet != 0)
    {

        bet = getBet(in, cash);

        char choice = getHighLow(in);

        int roll1 = getRoll();
        System.out.println("Dice 1 rolls: " + roll1);

        int roll2 = getRoll();
        System.out.println("Dice 2 rolls: " + roll2);

        int total = (roll1 + roll2);
        System.out.println("The total roll is: " + total);

        int winnings = determineWinnings(choice, bet, total);

        cash = cash + winnings;
    }

    System.out.println("You have " + cash + " dollars left. Goodbye!");



}


// Given a Scanner and a current maximum amount of money, prompt the user for
// an integer representing the number of dollars that they want to bet.  This
// number must be between 0 and to maximum number of dollars.  If the user enters
// a number that is out of bounds, display an error message and ask again.
// Return the bet to the calling program.
private static int getBet(Scanner inScanner, int currentPool) {
    System.out.println("You have " + currentPool + " dollars");
    System.out.println("Enter and amount to bet (0 to quit): ");

    int bet = inScanner.nextInt();


    while (0 > bet || currentPool < bet )
    {
        System.out.println("Your bet must be between 0 and " + currentPool + " dollars ");
        bet = inScanner.nextInt();
    }

    return bet;

}

// Given a Scanner, prompt the user for a single character indicating whether they
// would like to bet High ('H'), Low ('L') or Sevens ('S').  Your code should accept
// either capital or lowercase answers, but should display an error if the user attempts
// to enter anything but one of these 3 values and prompt for a valid answer.
// Return the character to the calling program.
private static char getHighLow(Scanner inScanner) {
    System.out.println("High, low or sevens (H/L/S): ");

    inScanner.nextLine();

    char choice = inScanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
    choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);

    while (choice != 'H' && choice != 'L' && choice != 'S')
    {
        System.out.println("You must choose between high, low or sevens (H/L/S): ");
        choice = Character.toUpperCase(inScanner.nextLine().charAt(0));
    }

    return choice;


}

// Produce a random roll of a single six-sided die and return that value to the calling
// program
private static int getRoll() {
    Random generate = new Random();

    int roll = generate.nextInt(6) + 1;

    return roll;

}

// Given the choice of high, low or sevens, the player's bet and the total result of
// the roll of the dice, determine how much the player has won.  If the player loses
// the bet then winnings should be negative.  If the player wins, the winnings should
// be equal to the bet if the choice is High or Low and 4 times the bet if the choice
// was Sevens.  Return the winnings to the calling program.
private static int determineWinnings(char highLow, int bet, int roll) {

    if(roll <= 6)
    {
        if(highLow == 'L')
        {
            System.out.println("You won " + bet + " dollars! ");
            return bet;
        }

        else
            System.out.println("You lose! ");
            return -bet;
    }

    else if (roll == 7)
    {
        if(highLow == 'S')
        {
            System.out.println("You won " + (bet * 4) + " dollars! ");
            return (bet * 4);
        }

        else
            System.out.println("You lose! ");
            return -bet;
    }

    else
    {
        if(highLow == 'H')
        {
            System.out.println("You won " + bet + " dollars! ");
            return bet;
        }

        else
            System.out.println("You lose! ");
            return -bet;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: As per the description, while condition seems fine. Are you seeing any error/unexpected behavior?

Comment: It looks like your code should work. Are you getting some errors?

Comment: Use one `while` loop, and convert the other `while` loops to `for` loops by simply replacing `while(condition)statement` to `for(;condition;)statement`

Comment: Use brackets like _while ( (choice != 'H' )&& (choice != 'L') && (choice != 'S') )_

Comment: Try to use ` do{}while()` loop . because difference between while and dowhile is dowhile will run at least one time

Comment: While this may sound silly, I want to avoid using things we have not yet learned in class. As I said im in a intro to java course. I have had no prior experience in programming either. We have not yet learned about dowhile  so my professor would not want us to use that.

Comment: @Cameron I edited my answer to make the game end as soon as bet equals 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `while(cash > 0 || bet != 0)` to `while(cash > 0 && bet != 0)`

This is because, you want to end the game if either cash equals 0 or when bet equals 0. If you use the `||` then only when both variables are 0 will the loop stop. If you use the `&&` then the loop will stop if either of the variables are 0.

when `&&` is used, **both** conditions must be true for the loop to **execute**. If **one** condition is true and the other is false then, the loop will **stop**.

when `||` is used, **any one**
 condition must be true for the loop to **execute**. If both conditions are true the the loop will run. If one of the conditions is false and the other is true then, it will still run. If **both** conditions are **false** then, the loop will **stop**.

**EDIT:**

If you want the program to end as soon as the bet variable is 0 then just add these lines after `bet = getBet(in, cash);`:

```
if(bet<=0){
 System.out.println("You are out of cash!");
 break;
}
```

Hope this helped:)

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I feel like a lot of people get confused on this. I wonder if there's some post we can make.

Comment: @goodguy5 Well, we could just refer them to this question  every time a person asks a similar question.

Comment: Even if I do that the loop will still continue to run. I want the game to end immediately once bet is assigned the value 0.

Comment: @Paul works for me. This is actually one of the best examples I can find in 5 minutes. If I get really ambitious, I might suggest a couple edits, but it's late, so probably not.

Comment: @Paul I meant to say I want the loop to end once bet is 0. Kind of like leaving the table with the money I won.

Comment: @Paul I used it and it works thank you so much. I wanted to see if there was a way I could do it without having to use break was all